# Resolve mainWindow() to full name?

Tags: cocoa, ios-ui-automation

I am using the UI Automation classes from Apple. The (desktop) application I am attempting to automate has multiple windows. Using `UIAElement`, I can get the element where my cursor is currently at. However, I've noticed that sometimes a window shows up as `mainWindow()`, and other times there's a longer name for it. I'm assuming this because `mainWindow()` is whichever window currently has focus.

Is there a way to get a "canonical" name for `mainWindow()`? For example: assume, I have `target.processes()["MyApp"].windows()["Window1"]` and `target.processes()["MyApp"].windows()["Window2"]` and I am currently focused on `Window2`. Thus, `Window2` would show up as `target.processes()["MyApp"].mainWindow()` - but I'd like to find a way to resolve `mainWindow()` to the full name, so to speak.

Comment: Do you need to get the name of the window inside the script, programmatically?

Comment: Yes, I do.  The goal is to record what the user has clicked on, etc., and if some of the actions have mainWindow(), but I don't know which window was mainWindow() at that moment in time, it would be hard to deduce what the user was doing.

Answer (score 0):

First, you could set the unique identifiers for the windows inside the application:

```
[window1 setAccessibilityIdentifier:@"Window1"];
[window2 setAccessibilityIdentifier:@"Window2"];
```

Then, you should be able to access these identifiers inside the test script. The `.name()` should return `Window1` or `Window2` according to the window you were using at the moment:

```
var mainWindowName = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().name();
```

Also, here's the link to the documentation, in case you need it: [UI Automation JavaScript Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/UIAutomationRef/_index.html)

Comment: If you read my original question, I need to be able to figure out what mainWindow() was at that moment in time.  It is not a unique identifier.

Comment: @user2406467, well, according to the documentation, `.name()` is the only reliable identifier that you can get; you can set it inside your Objective-C source code to use it in your test code later. see my updated answer.